# TinyMCE + AngularJS - Keyup event triggered before update of ng-model

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui-tinymce

I am fairly new to AngularJS and the TinyMCE editor. I was fiddling around with the `keyup` event available in TinyMCE when I came across this issue. In the `keyup` handler, I am accessing one of the `controller`'s `ng-model`. Here's where things start to get *odd*. I printed out the `ng-model` value and the editor's content for comparison purposes and it would seem that the `ng-model` is **lagging by 1 key/character behind** i.e. the editor's content is the most up to date. I have a hunch that the model is updated only *after* the keyup event is finished. That would explain why I am seeing two values here. Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way? Speaking of which, what would be the best/correct way to access the editor's contents? Through angular or TinyMCE?

If it helps, the code looks something like this (They are placed under a single `controller`):-

```
        ...
        this.text = "";
        var viewModel = this;
        this.tinymceOptions = {
              setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('keyup', function (e) {
                  console.log(editor.getContent());
                  console.log(viewModel.text);
                });
              },
              ...
       };
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: did you got the solution for the above problem ? i am also the facing the same issue

Comment: Hey, @SivaRajini. I created a workaround to the problem, instead. Essentially, I used TinyMCE's keyup handler to count the number of words that are currently on the editor. Then, I assign that count to a variable within my controller's scope. That way, my controller would have access to the wordCount when it needs to. It did the job in my case. Unfortunately, I have not heard back from the TinyMCE developers on a fix to this problem. Will still keep a lookout, though. Hope that helps. :)